# Text Color Masking with Animation using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to show the text text masking effect with animation

**Here is my fiddle for what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/qTWTH/**

This is not working completely, the effect which I am getting for "**`Waiting`**"  is what I want for complete text, where as right now, after "Waiting" the red text pause and change the color of whole work all together.

Also how to hide the full "Red text", it should only be visible while masking.

Code:
**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span id="black">Waiting for the task!</span>
    <span id="red">Waiting for the task!</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#black {
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:2em;
}
#red {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    left:8px;
    width:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:2em;
    color:red;
}
```

**JS**

```
var red = document.getElementById('red');
var black = document.getElementById('black');
red.style.width = "0px";
var animation = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(red.style.width);
    if (red.style.width == "290px") clearInterval(animation);
    red.style.width = parseInt(red.style.width, 10) + 1 + "px";
}, 50);
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS to your `#red` selector properties:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qTWTH/1/

Comment: @AT-UID I'm glad you made a fiddle otherwise it would have been hard to figure out.